# Mixing async-await with fire-and-forget approach

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, fire-and-forget

I'm writing a websocket server using .NET's `HttpListener` class.

Essentially, I've got a `HandleListener()` function which wait for clients to connect and yield each client  to `HandleClient(WebSocket client)`. So I currently have:

```
    private async void HandleListener()
    {
        try
        {
            while (listener != null && listener.IsListening)
            {
                HttpListenerContext listenerContext = await listener.GetContextAsync();
                WebSocketContext webSocketContext = await listenerContext.AcceptWebSocketAsync(subProtocol: null);
                WebSocket webSocket = webSocketContext.WebSocket;
                clients.Add(webSocket);
                await HandleClient(webSocket);
            }
        }
        catch (HttpListenerException) { } // Got here probably because StopWSServer() was called
    }

private async Task HandleClient(WebSocket client) { ... }
```

Problem is, I can't seem to process more then one client. It looks like the execution of `HandleListener()` halts as long as the first client is connected.

I tried removing the `await` from the call to `HandleClient()`, but I get the "because this call is not awaited..." error. I can make `HandleClient()` a `async void` method, but this is not an event handler.
BTW, the reason that `HandleClient()` is `async Task` is because it's doing, all over in a loop until the listener is dead:

```
recieveResult = await client.ReceiveAsync(recievedBuffer, CancellationToken.None);
```

From what I understand, a fire-and-forget approach is bad overall, and I can't seem to achieve it with async-await implementation. But `HandleClient()` **is** a fire-and-forget method, and I don't see any other way of achieving what I need.

---

EDIT: Added current implementation of `HandleClient()`:

```
   private async Task HandleClient(WebSocket client)
    {
        try
        {
            ArraySegment<byte> recievedBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]);
            while (listener != null && listener.IsListening && client.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                WebSocketReceiveResult recieveResult;
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        recieveResult = await client.ReceiveAsync(recievedBuffer, CancellationToken.None);
                        ms.Write(recievedBuffer.Array, recievedBuffer.Offset, recieveResult.Count);
                    }
                    while (!recieveResult.EndOfMessage);
                    switch (recieveResult.MessageType)
                    {
                        case WebSocketMessageType.Close:
                            RemoveClient(client, WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty);
                            break;
                        case WebSocketMessageType.Binary:
                            RemoveClient(client, WebSocketCloseStatus.InvalidMessageType, "Cannot accept binary frame");
                            break;
                        case WebSocketMessageType.Text:
                            OnRecieve?.Invoke(client, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebSocketException ex)
        {
            RemoveClient(client, WebSocketCloseStatus.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `HandleClient` do? You say it's fire and forget. But why is it async then?

Comment: It's async because it does `...await client.ReceiveAsync...` all over in a loop. I've edited the question to include this.

Comment: But that's not fire and forget. When you are waiting for the receive to complete, you are not forgetting. It seems the issue is in the structure of your code. One line from `HandleClient` is not enough to help to resolve that.

Comment: I've added the `HandleClient()` implementation.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent compiler warning, use method like this:

```
public static class TaskExtensions {
    public static void Forget(this Task task) {

    }
}
```

then just do

```
HandleClient(webSocket).Forget()
```

If you go this route, ensure that you handle all exceptions inside `HandleClient` somehow (wrap whole thing into try-catch for example). There is nothing inherently "bad" in this approach in this particular case.

Alternative approach would be:

```
HandleClient(webSocket).ContinueWith(task => {
    if (task.IsFaulted && task.Exception != null) {
        // handle it here
    }
});
```

awaiting `HandleClient` is not an option in this case, as you see yourself.

Answer (score 1):

it will do like that because you wrote code for it, my mean to say you wrote method as below.

```
   private async void HandleListener()
    {
        try
        {
            while (listener != null && listener.IsListening)
            {
                HttpListenerContext listenerContext = await listener.GetContextAsync();
                WebSocketContext webSocketContext = await listenerContext.AcceptWebSocketAsync(subProtocol: null);
                WebSocket webSocket = webSocketContext.WebSocket;
                clients.Add(webSocket);
                await HandleClient(webSocket);
            }
        }
        catch (HttpListenerException) { } // Got here probably because StopWSServer() was called
    }
```

In this method when it encounter `await` control will get return to orignal caller ,till you await part got completed and next call start after it.

Check below image this how await and async works

[image]

If you just want fire and forget than try like this

```
   private void HandleListener()
    {
        try
        {
            while (listener != null && listener.IsListening)
            {
                HttpListenerContext listenerContext = await listener.GetContextAsync();
                WebSocketContext webSocketContext = await listenerContext.AcceptWebSocketAsync(subProtocol: null);
                WebSocket webSocket = webSocketContext.WebSocket;
                clients.Add(webSocket);
                HandleClient(webSocket);
            }
        }
        catch (HttpListenerException) { } // Got here probably because StopWSServer() was called
    }
```

which means dont wait for completion of task

Comment: This is a highly risky approach. You don't know whether `HandleClient` is `async` itself and what it does.

Comment: Actually, `HandleClient` is `async`

Comment: @Sefe - know but he wants fire and forget scenario that why i wrote code

Comment: @galah92 - in that case you just remove  Task.Factory.StartNew( this call

Comment: But then I get "because this call is not awaited..." warning, and it feels like it's not a good practice.

Comment: @galah92 - but you want fire and forget scenario right ?, than you can ignore warning .....I warning is for you are not writing async and await ..that is you choice and it based on scenario ...if you dont do that than better to forget about fire / forget senario